# pdf contents not getting on live but working on localhost

Tags: pdf, codeigniter-3, dompdf

Here am using dompdf to generate pdf file.For that i had included the code like this..
My control looks like this

```
<?php
require_once (APPPATH.'helpers/dompdf/autoload.inc.php');
use Dompdf\Dompdf;
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
class Account_control extends CI_Controller {
 function __construct() 
 {
  parent::__construct();       
  $this->load->model('Account_model');
  $this->load->library('num_to_words');

 }
function bill_print($id = NULL){

$this->load->helper('file');
$data['result'] = $this->Account_model->bill_print($id)->row();
$result = $data['result'];
$invoice = $result->invoice_no;
$data['products'] = $this->Account_model->get_all_products()->result();
$dompdf = New DOMPDF();
$html = $this->load->view('pdf', $data, TRUE);
$dompdf->loadHtml($html);
$dompdf->render();
$dompdf->stream("{$invoice}", array("Attachment"=>0));
}
```

}

am getting pdf result like this on live
[image]

but in lcalhost am getting perfectly like this
[image]

please help me to solve my problem

Comment: please help me to solve

Comment: hello any idea..

Comment: Remove first occurrence of `$dompdf = new Dompdf();` (line 4). Seems like you don't have data in DB (is that possible)? You can debug it in a way that you can put `var_dump($data);exit;` just before second occurrence of instantiating Dompdf object.

Comment: by removing `$dompdf = new Dompdf();` ,still it looks same